# WARNING: /bin/sh is not bash! - No tftp server found

Tags: 20.04

I need to launch Petalinux but I get warning that /bin/sh is not bash !

Here is the terminal.

```
abc@alpha:/scratch2/abc/Xilinx$ source Petalinux/settings.sh
PetaLinux environment set to '/scratch2/abc/Xilinx/Petalinux'
WARNING: /bin/sh is not bash! 
bash is PetaLinux recommended shell. Please set your default shell to bash.
WARNING: This is not a supported OS
INFO: Checking free disk space
INFO: Checking installed tools
INFO: Checking installed development libraries
INFO: Checking network and other services
WARNING: No tftp server found - please refer to "UG1144 2021.1 PetaLinux Tools Documentation Reference Guide" for its impact and solution
abc@alpha:/scratch2/abc/Xilinx$
```

Then I tried to run chsh -s /bin/bash but it says that user 'abc' does not exist in etc/passwd

```
abc@alpha:/scratch2/abc/Xilinx/Petalinux$ chsh -s /bin/bash
Password: 
chsh: user 'abc' does not exist in /etc/passwd
```

Then I tried to add user with a command passwd abc. It ask me current and new password. Which current password should I use here ? I tried to use the password of user 'abc' as current and some other as new password but then it says Authentication token manipulation error and password unchanged.

```
abc@alpha:/scratch2/abc/Xilinx/Petalinux$ passwd abc
Current Password: 
New password: 
BAD PASSWORD: The password is shorter than 8 characters
New password: 
Retype new password: 
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
abc@alpha:/scratch2/abc/Xilinx/Petalinux$
```

Comment: I think you have made this too complicated. If your terminal uses the sh shell change it’s setting to use bash or just issue the command bash to switch to bash for the current session

Comment: Do you mean to run `bash source Petalinux/settings.sh`. Will bash the current session ?

Comment: `abc@alpha:/scratch2/abc/Xilinx/Petalinux$ sudo chmod +x settings.sh
[sudo] password for abc: 
abc@alpha:/scratch2/abc/Xilinx/Petalinux$ bash source /settings.sh
bash: source: No such file or directory`

Comment: How about "No tftp server found". Can I install or enable the tftp server ?

Comment: Presumably you can if you refer to the documentation as suggested in the warning message and follow the guidance.

Answer (score 2):

When you first open your terminal issue the command:

```
echo $SHELL
```

That will tell you what shell you are using. If it’s /bin/sh you can switch to bash by just typing :

```
bash
```

Then you can try the commands that gave you warnings. If you still don’t have a tftp server refer to the documentation as suggested by the warning message. You may need to install something or start a service

Comment: I get `/bin/bash` when I run this command `echo $SHELL`.

Comment: So you have bash when you open the terminal. What do you get after you run the source petalinux/settings.sh command?

Comment: Hi, If I run this command then I get exactly the same which I have posted in the original post.            WARNING: This is not a supported OS INFO: Checking free disk space INFO: Checking installed tools INFO: Checking installed development libraries INFO: Checking network and other services WARNING: No tftp server found - please refer to "UG1144 2021.1 PetaLinux Tools Documentation Reference Guide" for its impact and solution abc@alpha:/scratch2/abc/Xilinx

Comment: So the bash warning is no longer there? Looks like petalinux expects tftp to be there already. A simple Google search for “install tftp” reveals several guides such as this https://linuxhint.com/install_tftp_server_ubuntu/

Comment: Note that you only have warning messages here. A tftp server is only needed if you are going to do something with this software that requires one. Most functions will work fine. The same applies to the os version. Ubuntu 20.04.1 is guaranteed to work. 20.04.3 will probably work

Comment: To anyone who ends up here because they are having a similar issue: typing `/usr/bin/bash -c <COMMAND>` and replacing <COMMAND> with any command will run that command in a bash shell. Additionally, running `/usr/bin/bash` with no arguments will switch you to a bash shell as long as bash is properly installed. In this situation, however, the OP was already in bash. I believe that a line of code in the sourced script caused the warning.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended action in the petalinux docs successfully got rid of the warning. Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash`, then select no when prompted. Now you should no longer get "WARNING: /bin/sh is not bash".